# PHP - How to get variable name + array key passed by a function

Tags: php

Array with keys:

```
$foo = array('id' => '123');
```

When I call this function:

```
printVarNameAndKey($foo['id']);
```

Print out:

```
$foo['id']
```

Is this possible in PHP?

**EDIT**

This code does not work:

```
function print_var_name($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $var_name => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $var_name;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: do u want $foo['id'] as output ?

Comment: No, you are just sending the value of a variable to your function so php has no way of knowing if it is part of a larger data structure.

Comment: What you want to do ?

Comment: Print out variable name and array key.

Comment: You cannot do that, a value does not uniquely identify a variable.

Answer (score 0):

$GLOBALS is not a super-global, you may update your code to look like

```
function print_var_name($var) {
    global $GLOBALS;
    foreach($GLOBALS as $var_name => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $var_name;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

but as @jeroen said, a value does not uniquely identify a variable.

Comment: This code in edit works if printVarNameAndKey($foo). But does not work well: printVarNameAndKey($foo['id']);